Why is helium in excited state with $S = 1$ more stable than $S = 0$?
In molecular physics, we were told that helium is more stable with total spin $S = 1$ than $S = 0$, so with $1s^12s^1$. I don't understand why.

Where is this asserted?

I was about to answer but then fund the notation surprising. Could you check it? Did you mean 1s2s (which is possible for a single atom) or do you have in mind an extra electron? Also you mentioned molecular physics but is this question in fact just about atomic helium?

I guess your configuration should read $1s^12s^1$ instead of $1s^12s^2$, otherwise it is not helium. This configuration can give rise to $S=0$ and $S=1$ states (with symmetric and antisymmetric spatial parts, respectively), the latter having lower energy in accordance with Hund's first rule.

There was a mistake in the original post, I've fixed it

Helium is most stable in its ground state (where the configuration is $1\mathrm{s}^2$) and the term symbol is ${}^1$S. However, for the first excited state of helium (configuration $1\mathrm{s}^12\mathrm{s}^1$), the ${}^3$S term is lower energy than the $^{1}S$ term, which requires a lengthy calculation to show (although people have come up with vaguely reasonable physical heuristics to explain it).

This is ultimately a consequence of Pauli's exclusion principle
(saying that the total wavefunction $\psi$ of all the electrons
in an atom needs to be antisymmetric).
Applied to the two electrons in the helium atom this means,
we have two different kinds of electronic states:

The spin part of $\psi$ is antisymmetric
(i.e. antiparallel electron spins, total spin $S=0$).
$\Rightarrow$ The orbital part of $\psi$ is symmetric
$\quad$(the electrons tend to be on the same side from the nucleus)
$\Rightarrow$ the electrons are closer to each other
$\Rightarrow$ more Coulomb repulsion between the electrons
$\Rightarrow$ higher total energy
The spin part of $\psi$ is symmetric
(i.e. parallel electron spins, total spin $S=1$).
$\Rightarrow$ The orbital part of $\psi$ is antisymmetric
$\quad$(the electrons tend to be on opposite sides from the nucleus)
$\Rightarrow$ the electrons are further apart from each other
$\Rightarrow$ less Coulomb repulsion between the electrons
$\Rightarrow$ lower total energy

Because of this the $S=1$ state of a certain configuration
(for example $1s^12s^1$) has a lower total energy
than the $S=0$ state of the same configuation (here $1s^12s^1$).
See also Hyperphysics - Helium Energy Levels - Orthohelium and
Parahelium Energy Levels for a more elaborate explanation on this topic.

Beware: this traditional explanation of Hund's rule (triplet energy being lower because of the Fermi hole) has turned out to be incorrect. Accurate numerical calculations show that the e-e repulsion is actually larger for triplet states, and the true cause of the lower energy is the smaller shielding effect on the nucleus; see the references in my answer.

If the spin of the exited state is antiparallel to the spin in ground state, the matrix element is nearly the same as for spinless particles, because the free state is the same spin vector component. The dipole moment between two S-states is zero, so at least quadrupole transitions with a low probability are involved.
If the spins are different, the free ground state is spin-orthogonal in the Pauli basis to the exited state of the same total angular momentum.
It follows, that the matrix element with powers of the coordinates for a multipole transition is an effect of the perturbation induced by the electron-electron interaction only. Again, dipole elements for two S states are zero or very small by perturbation. Which rate is larger is a question of detailed perturbation theory.
